# DB2:: Impact on code due to increase in database tablespace

Tags: sql, database, optimization, db2, tablespace

We have a large table with **260 million records**. The current size of the tables is 50 GB and that of tablespace in which table recides is 65GB. Once the size exceeds the limit, We will not be able to do any transaction on this table.

**Problem statement:** We need to overcome the problem which might occur if the table size exceeds.

**Our abopted solution:** We will increase the table space from 65GB to 2 TB so that there will be no impact.
We also consider below options as well
[Optimizing large tablespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042343/optimizing-large-tablespace), however shortlisted above option.

**My quetions:** Will increase in tablespace impacts (JAVA) code(I m sure it won't.. still curious to know if it does ...as could not find any such article specifying the same).

Answer (score 1):

Provided your java code is sending SQLL queries and using the driver's API, the change in space should be completely transparent to the Java application.